Showing records/data from another database table based on the id in laravel
Hello Please I am trying to view the records of a user based on the user id I used as a foreign key in another table in laravel. Basically I want the name of the userID to show.
This is my Controller
    public function index()
    {
       
        
        $id = User::all();
        $organisedTrips = organisedTrip::where('userID', '=', $id)->get();
    
        $organisedTrips = organisedTrip::paginate(4);
        return view('welcome', compact('organisedTrips'));
        
    }





$id = User::all() the $id will be an array here! it should be an int, and you are overriding the $organisedTrips variable, why is that? do you want to apply the userId condition and use the pagination or not ? please correct your code

User::all() returns array of the users. Consider using pluck function and correct your code.
public function index()
    {
       
        
        $id = User::all()->pluck('id');
        $organisedTrips = organisedTrip::whereIn('userID', $id)->get();
    
        $organisedTrips = organisedTrip::paginate(4);
        return view('welcome', compact('organisedTrips'));
        
    }

Tip:
It can be done in better way using eloquent.

$id will be an array so where condition will only satisfy the first element of the array. Consider using whereIn.Eg whereIn('userId',$id)->paginate(4);

Thank you. I've updated my answer as suggested

in whereIn 2nd arguement is an array so whereIn('userID', '=', $id) is incorrect. Should be whereIn('userID',  $id)

I have done all suggested but it still displays the user id instead of their names

You can use auth() because this is the simplest and safest way
enter image description here
Or you can separate model and controller
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried this before and it worked.

When I write the code that way from the pictures you have provided above it doesn't even display the database records in my view
